# Return second item from a subquery

Tags: sql-server, database

i want to return the second item from this subquery:

```
set GrowerNumber =(select top 1 tea_no
  from ktda_file
  where ktda_file.fosa_acno=customer.fosa_acno)
```

Comment: GrowerNumber =(select top 1 tea_no  from ktda_file where ktda_file.fosa_acno=customer.fosa_acno)

Comment: you did not specify sort order, so you already have good chances to obtain 2nd or 3rd item as well

Answer (score 1):

```
GrowerNumber = (
  select top 1
    tea_no
  from
    (
      select top 2
        tea_no
      from
        ktda_file
      where ktda_file.fosa_acno=customer.fosa_acno
    ) as a
  order by
    tea_no desc
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
WITH CTE AS
( 
 SELECT top 2 tea_no  from ktda_file
 WHERE ktda_file.fosa_acno=customer.fosa_acno
 ORDER BY tea_no ASC
)     
SELECT TOP 1 tea_no  FROM CTE ORDER BY tea_no DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
        Item1 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.RowNum = 1 THEN t.tea_no END),
        Item2 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.RowNum = 2 THEN t.tea_no END)
    FROM (
        SELECT tea_no, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tea_no)
        FROM ktda_file
        WHERE ktda_file.fosa_acno = customer.fosa_acno
    ) t
    WHERE RowNum < 3
) t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
(select tea_no from (select row_number() over ( order by tea_no asc) as rowID,  tea_no from ktda_file where ktda_file.fosa_acno=customer.fosa_acno)x where rowID = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to do something like this (as Ivan said, you dont have an order by in your query, so what is the 2nd one?) Nevertheless assuming it is tea_no...

```
GrowerNumber = (Select tea_no  from (select row_number() over (order by tea_no) as row
    from ktda_file where ktda_file.fosa_acno=customer.fosa_acno) as orderedlist
    where row = 2)
```